# Android Object Animator throwing cannot resolve type

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an Object Animator in Android using the following code:

```
ObjectAnimator animation = new ObjectAnimator.ofInt(...);
```

although the compiler keeps throwing an error under "`ofInt`" saying:

> Cannot resolve Symbol '`ofInt`'

What am I doing wrong it's driving me crazy.

Comment: can you post a bit more code and the logcat

Comment: Not sure what else I can add in terms of code as everything else is unrelated.. but heres this: C:\Users\R830\Documents\Projects\ArcticEscape\app\src\main\java\com\desirenetworks\arcticescape\Level1.java
Error:(56, 54) error: cannot find symbol class ofInt
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answered :)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
new ObjectAnimator().ofInt(..)
```

i think youre forgetting () *constructor/method call

Comment: Wow I am such an idiot! Sorry and thank you so much!

Comment: happens to the best of us (:

Answer (score 1):

The call `ObjectAnimator animation = new ObjectAnimator.ofInt(...);`
is wrong, you need to call the constructor properly and then call the methods you need...

```
ObjectAnimator animation = new ObjectAnimator();
animation.ofInt(...);
```